# Install Apache 2 on a Linux server

Tags: linux, apache

I've modified the listening port to 8080. But when I run 'apachetcl start', the error message still occurs as:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I've also checked the Apache error log.

```
[Wed Dec 09 12:39:16.457678 2015] [mpm_event:notice]
[pid 96777:tid 139998996637568] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7
(Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
   [Wed Dec 09 12:39:16.457753 2015] [core:notice] [pid 96777:tid 139998996637568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

How do I suppress this message?

Comment: Where did you change port to 8080? In your log apache tried connect to port 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem:

1. Open `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

   TO THE TOP ADD: ServerName localhost

   Close now!
2. OPEN `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

You will see two 80 or 443 or 8080. Delete one and save... Now

```
apachetcl start
```

Or you can do:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'

sudo kill -9 2242
```

Then restart `apache2`:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then start it

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: It works!  I can start Apache on the Linux server now,but still cannot  browse the default html on my windows browser.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to JM511's response, but in a different order of operations. The method they recommended just had `apache2` restarting itself with a new process id and still occupying the port.

```
sudo etc/init.d/apache2 stop

sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'

sudo kill -9 2178 #killed the process id of the process listening to port 80

sudo opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```